# Updating a dependency variable after execution of useEffect without triggering that useEffect hook again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

As shown in the following react code snippet, I have a useEffect hook with a dependency 'fetchQuery'. The useEffect hook will execute if 'fetchQuery' variable changes. But right after execution of it, I want to clear the value (set to '') of that dependency variable 'fetchQuery' without triggering an infinite loop. Is there a way to do that?

```
useEffect(() => {
        // An async function to fetch some data
        getDataModules(fetchQuery);
    }, [fetchQuery]);
```

Since 'fetchQuery' is a state variable and is given as a dependency for this hook, simply clearing its value using `setFetchQuery('');` will trigger useEffect again, which I dont want.

Comment: Wanting to do this is *possibly* indicative of a larger architectural flaw. Can you give context of where else `fetchQuery` is used, what is for, and what it contains?

Answer (score 0):

Only call the API if `fetchQuery` exists.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (fetchQuery) {
        getDataModules(fetchQuery);
    }
}, [fetchQuery]);
```

Do `setFetchQuery('');` to clear.

Comment: But 'fetchQuery' is a query. Even if it is empty string, API needs to be called without any input parameters, except when I just want to clear the variable. E.g. if fetchQuery can have value "success==true", API will fetch the records where success field is true. If fetchQuery is "", API will have to fetch all the records.

Comment: You could choose a way to identify a clearly invalid query. If the empty string won't do, how about a non-string, like `null`? `if (fetchQuery !== null) { ...` But for an API request, it'd make more sense for this to not be in its own effect hook, and instead be in, say, a button click handler.

Comment: This method of setting fetchQuery to some invalid value works for now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [shouldRefetch, setShouldRefetch] = useState(false);

const [fetchQuery, setFetchQuery] = useState(...);

useEffect(() => {
  if (shouldRefetch) {
    getDatamodules(fetchQuery);
    setShouldRefetch(false);
    setFetchQuery('');
  }
}, [shouldRefetch]);


const someOtherFunction = () => {
  setFetchQuery(...);
  SetShouldRefetch(true);
};
```